# I am trying to code the simplecart.js to add more than 1 newitem when the add to cart is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplecart

I am trying to code the simplecart.js to add more than 1 newitem when the add to cart is clicked.   Like 2 adults and 1 teenager and 1 child along with the prices for each.

```
        // add in the core functionality
        simpleCart.extend({

            isReady: false,

            // this is where the magic happens, the add function
            add: function (values, opt_quiet) {
                var info        = values || {},
                    newItem     = new simpleCart.Item(info),
                    addItem     = true,
                    // optionally supress event triggers
                    quiet       = opt_quiet === true ? opt_quiet : false,
                    oldItem;

                // trigger before add event
                if (!quiet) {
                    addItem = simpleCart.trigger('beforeAdd', [newItem]);

                    if (addItem === false) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                // if the new item already exists, increment the value
                oldItem = simpleCart.has(newItem);
                if (oldItem) {
                    oldItem.increment(newItem.quantity());
                    newItem = oldItem;

                // otherwise add the item
                } else {
                    sc_items[newItem.id()] = newItem;
                }
```

Comment: Must ask a question about a specific problem (like stack overflow error :-) or another coding issue) that you are having

Comment: the problem is if I add to two item_names and quantity the add to cart won't push them to the cart.  It will only push one newitem with the quantity.

Comment: It doesn't appear that this is a coding issue - that's how this cart has been coded. What I was trying to say was that to be able to get help here, you need to attempt something, fail, look for solution on the wider web and come here for very specific, unanswered question(s). In your case, you need to modify the `add` function or code a new one called addMultiple, but those aren't usually things that fall within the scope of the discussion here. Pls see [help] for more info on SO